# VB.net Histogram - how to bin data

Tags: vb.net, statistics, histogram, binning

I'm working on a histogram class and in particular a binning method.

In relation hereto I have two questions:

1. Is it a right/appropriate algorithm seen from a logic/statistical point of view
2. Is the code optimal or at least decent - please tell me how to improve it

Any help is highly appreciated - thx in advance.

Here is my code so far...

```
Public Class Histo
Dim data() As Double
Dim bins As Integer = 0
Dim bw As Double = 0
Dim _min As Double = 0
Dim _max As Double = 0
Dim arrMax As Double = 0
Dim cht As Chart
Public shared Decimals As Integer

Public Sub New(_arr() As Double, _cht As Chart)
    'One-dimensional array as data
    data = _arr

    'No of bins with Sturges method
    bins  = NoBin_ST(data)

    'calculate bin width
    bw = Range(data) / bins

    'bin boundries for first bin 
    _min = Min(data)
    _max = _min + bw

    'max of data
    arrMax = Max(data)

    'chart object
    cht = _cht

    'no of decimals on x-axis
    Decimals = Dec
End Sub

Public Function Binning() As Integer()
    'Binning "algorihtm" for continuous data
    '
    'RETURN: one-dimensional array with n bins
    '
    Array.Sort(data)
    Dim j As Integer = 0
    Dim mn As Double = _min
    Dim mx As Double = _max
    Dim counter(bins-1) As Integer

    For i As Integer = 0 To data.GetLength(0)-1
        'check if data point is within the boundries of the current bin     
        If data(i) >= mn AndAlso data(i) < mx Then
            'add counter in current bin
            counter(j) += 1
        Else
            'special case: at the end at least one data point will equal max of the last bin
            ' and must be counted in that bin
            If data(i) = arrMax  Then
                counter(j) += 1
                Continue For
            End If
            'the data point has exceeded the boundries of the previous bin 
            ' and must be counted in the next bin
            'min and max is increased with the bin width
            mn += bw
            mx += bw
            'go to next bin
            j += 1
            'count data point in this bin and loop again
            counter(j) += 1
        End If
    Next
    Return counter
End Function

.....
```

Comment: Rather than keeping arrMax in your New, you could have Binning just loop through one less data point and then always copy the last data point into the last bin.  That would eliminate the need to find the maximum value.

Comment: Did the [answer by Garath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56188511/1115360) solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is any more performant, but I think it is a bit simpler.

```
Function CreateBins(values As IEnumerable(Of Double), numberOfBins As Integer) As IGrouping(Of Integer, Double)()
        If values Is Nothing Then Throw New Exception("Values cannot be null")
        If values.Distinct.Count < 2 Then Throw New Exception("Values must contain at least two ditinct elements")
        If numberOfBins < 1 Then Throw New Exception("numberOfBins must be an integer > 1")

        Dim min = values.Min
        Dim max = values.Max
        Dim binSize = (max - min) / numberOfBins
        ' Checking for two distinct elements should eliminate possibility of min=max and therefore binsize=0

        Dim bins = values.GroupBy(Function(x) Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor((x - min) / binSize))).ToArray

        ' Group counts available using the ienumerable Count function
        ' Dim counts = bins.Select(Function(x) x.Count)
        ' Or retaining the group key
        ' Dim counts = bins.Select(Function(x) New With {Key x.Key, x.Count})

        Return bins
End Function
```

Each bin is now a group. The original values are retained as part of the group, allowing potential follow up analysis. Count is available using the group function Count()